# paulvl/backup - Command Execution backup:mysql-dump custom_name

Tags: laravel, backup

I want to write code for Executing Artisan command::
I have written already this:

```
public function execute(){

    Artisan::call('backup:mysql-dump');
```

it works. Creates Whole Database Backup
My Question is that how to write Code for Artisan Command:
(To Specify Backup File .sql Name from Code)

```
backup:mysql-dump custom_name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add argument to Artisan:call

```
    $file_name = 'backup_' . date('m-d-Y_h_i_s_a');
    //Generate Backup
    Artisan::call('backup:mysql-dump', ["filename" => $file_name]);
```